# how to mix multithreading with sequential requirement?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i have a program which process price data coming from the broker. the pseudo code are as follow:

```
 Process[] process = new Process[50];

 void tickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int contractNumber = e.contractNumber;

    doPriceProcess(process[contractNumber], e);
 }
```

now i would like to use mutlithreading to speed up my program, if the data are of different contract number, i would like to fire off different threads to speed up the process. However if the data are from the same contract, i would like the program to wait until the current process finishes before i continue with the next data. How do i do it?

can you provide some code please?

thanks in advance~

Comment: Why do you make the assumption that adding more threads will speed the process up?

Comment: With every `tickEvent` you are getting one contract number. So what numbers do you want to compare for equality ?

Comment: @BryanCrosby - way do you think that it's an assumption? Splitting off the retrieval of price data from its handling and handling multiple brokers concurrently would seem like reasonable goals for such an app - easily handled by  multithreaded system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many high level architectural decissions to make here:

How many ticks do you expect to come from that broker?

After all, you should have some kind dispatcher here.

Here is some simple description of what basically is to do:

- Encapsulate the incoming ticks in packages, best 
  single commands that have all the data needed
- Have a queue where you can easily (and thread safe) can store those commands
- Have a Dispatcher, that takes an item of the queue and assigns some worker
  to do the command (or let the command execute itself)
- Having a worker, you can have multiple threads, processes or whatsoever
  to work multiple commands seemlessly
- Maybe you want to do some dispatching already for the input queue, depending
  on how many requests you want to be able to complete per time unit.

Here is some more information that can be helpful:

[Command pattern in C#](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx)

[Reactor pattern (with sample code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern)

Comment: +1 for a sensible design for such a system.  Queueing incoming ticks to a private queue of a  'contract object' that is submitted, (or resubmitted) to a threadpool to process each tick sequentially sounds good.

Comment: Thank you. Hope that the OP will judge it in a similar way.

Comment: i am thinking to have a thread pool of 1 thread for each contract, it will force the program to work sequentially on each contract, am i right?

Comment: If you assign a thread to each contract by some id, they will work on those contracts sequentially. Make sure that each thread can store the contracts, so that it will not block when working. This can also be achieved with queues as described in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than holding onto an array of `Process`es, I would hold onto an array of `BlockingCollection`s.  Each blocking collection can correspond to a particular contract.  Then you can have producer threads that add work to do onto the end of a corresponding contract's queue, and you can have producer queues that consume the results from those collections.  You can ensure than each thread (I would use threads for this, not processes) is handling 1-n different queues, but that each queue is handled by no more than one thread.  That way you can ensure that no bits of work from the same contract are worked on in parallel.

The threading aspect of this can be handled effectiving using C#'s `Task` class.  For your consumers you can create a new task for each `BlockingCollection`.  That task's body will pretty much just be:

```
foreach(SomeType item in blockingCollections[contractNumber].GetConsumingEnumerable())
  processItem(item);
```

However, by using `Task`s you will let the computer schedule them as it sees fit.  If it notices most of them sitting around waiting on empty queues it will just have a few (or just one) actual thread rotating between the tasks that it's using.  If they are trying to do enough, and your computer can clearly support the load of additional threads, it will add more (possibly adding/removing dynamically as it goes).  By letting much smarter people than you or I handle that scheduling it's much more likely to be efficient without under or over parallelizing.

Comment: i look at both answers, i have to say due to my (lack of) c# skills, i dont really understand the answers. but i think this may work, i will create a buffer for each contract that i have, price data coming in are store into the buffers to ensure no data are missed, then i will let my program to process the data as soon as possible.

Comment: Yeah, this is eseentially the same as @Mare Infinitus answer, and is the way I would do it too. It will work fine: I have used such designs/patterns many times.

Comment: thanks, i just don't understand all the c# lingo yet. i think i understand it conceptually, i need to put it in my own words, and thank martin for confirming it